# Fetch data horizontally

Tags: excel, vba

This is a simple example of initial state of Sheet1:

```
 |   A  |   B  |   C  |   D  |   E  |
1|   101|   102|   103|   104|   105|
2|      |      |      |      |      |
3|      |      |      |      |      |
```

This is a simple example of the data in Sheet2:

```
 |   A  |   B  |   C  |   D  |   E  |   F  |   G  |
1|Name1 |Name2 |Name3 |Name4 |Name5 |Name6 |Name7 |
2|101abc|106abc|107abc|104zyx|106def|102abc|101def|
3|106ghi|102def|104wvu|101ghi|107def|105zyx|104tsr|
4|101jkl|102ghi|101mno|101pqr|104qpo|106jkl|102jkl|
5|102mno|102pqr|104nml|106mno|101stu|104kji|102stu|
```

I am trying to write a macro that will extract data from Sheet2 and add it to Sheet1 to create:

```
 |   A  |   B  |   C  |   D  |   E  |
1|   101|   102|   103|   104|   105|
2|101abc|102abc|      |104zyx|105zyx|
3|101def|102def|      |104wvu|      |
4|101ghi|102ghi|      |104tsr|      |
5|101jkl|102jkl|      |104qpo|      |
6|101mno|102mno|      |104nml|      |
7|101pqr|102pqr|      |104kji|      |
8|101stu|102stu|      |      |      |
```

Row 1 of Sheet1 contains keywords identifying the values I wish to extract.

Row 1 of Sheet2 contains headers that are not relevant to the current macro.  The remaining rows contain values that start with keywords.  I am trying to extract the values from Sheet2 that match each keyword in Sheet1 and list them under the keyword.

It would be great if anyone helps me on this.

Comment: The question is not really clear... besides in order to get some help, you need to show what you tried and eventually someone will correct you

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Noldor.

Comment: If possible, can you try it now?

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but here's a hint: do some screenshots and attach them so people can SEE what your worksheets look like and don't get confused by the humongous list with # you wrote.
After that, a piece of code **written by you**, no matter how wrong it is, would show us what you are trying to achieve, so we can understand better...

Comment: I have formatted your tables as code so they are a little more readable.  However, the columns do not see to line up.  Perhaps you could edit your question yourself so the tables are clearer.  You do not have the reputation to post screen shots here but you could post them elsewhere and provide links.

Comment: I do not understand row 1 of Sheet 2. My guess is row 2 onwards are of the form: `Keyword1 space Value1, Keyword2 space Value2, Keyword3 space Value3, ...`  Row 1 of Sheet 1 contains selected keywords.  You want code to scan each row of Sheet 2 for those selected keywords and to place the corresponding value under its keyword. Is this guess correct?  I would not see this as difficult for an intermediate programmer.  How far have you got?

Comment: Thanks for the Response. I apologize that I have posted it in a hurry so it is very difficult for you to understand.

Comment: For better understanding,

Let's say that 

Sheet1 of workbook has a 10 headers like 101, 102, 103 till 110,

In Sheet2 of workbook let's assume that we are having 20 names / headers like Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4 till Name20


And Each Names / headers of Sheet2 will have it's corresponding values, the values can be infinitive.

Here, what all we have to do is, we have to do a search horizontally on sheet2 as per the header of sheet1 and needs to fetch the matching value on Sheet1

Comment: For example, here range ("a1") of Sheet1 is 101. We need a script, that will find this 101 in all cells of row 2 of Sheet2 and fill the value to Range ("a2") of Sheet1. To fill range ("a3") value of sheet1, we have to look third row of Sheet2.

Likewise I need to fetch value for all the headers in Sheet1 from Sheet2 horizontally.

Hope you understand!
Thanks

Comment: _Each Names / headers of Sheet2 will have it's corresponding values, the values can be infinitive._  What do you mean by _values_?  Where are they?  _For example, here range ("a1") of Sheet1 is 101. We need a script, that will find this 101 in all cells of row 2 of Sheet2 and fill the value to Range ("a2") of Sheet1._ What do you mean by _fill the value to Range("a2")_ if there can an infinite number of values?

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your question from your comments since it is important the question is clear and matches the answer.  Please make sure any future question is clear when you post it; do not rely on anyone being willing to tease the requirement out of you.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Report()

  ' Introduction to Version 1

  ' * I have set row 1 of Sheet1 to 101, 102, 103, 104 and 105
  ' * I have scattered the values 101, 102, 104 and 105 across Sheet2
  '   starting from cell A2.
  ' * For each value in row 1 of Sheet1, this macro either:
  '    * Reports it cannot find the value in Sheet2.
  '    * Lists the addresses of the cells containing the values.
  ' * I do not understand what you want to do when you discover cell XN
  '   contains a value from row 1 of Sheet1 so I have stored the addresses
  '   in a collection.  You may wish to keep the collection so you can
  '   process all the occurrences of a value at the same time (as I do)
  '   or you may discard the collection and process each value as you find
  '   it.

  ' Introduction to Version 2 which was created from version 1 after clarification
  ' of the contents of Sheet2 and clairification of the required output.

  ' * The appearances of Sheet1 and Sheet2 are now as shown in the question.
  ' * The values found (rather than the addresses) are now stored in the
  '   collection.
  ' * At the end of each repeat of the inner loop, the values found are now
  '   written to Sheet1 under the appropriate header

  Dim ColSht1Crnt As Long
  Dim InxL As Long
  Dim Locations As New Collection
  Dim RngFirst As Range
  Dim RngCrnt As Range
  Dim RowSht1Crnt As Long
  Dim SearchValue As String
  Dim Wsht1 As Worksheet
  Dim Wsht2 As Worksheet

  Set Wsht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set Wsht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

  ' Clear any data in Sheet1 stored by a previous run of this macro
  Wsht1.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Delete

  ColSht1Crnt = 1

  ' Each repeat of this outer loop processing a column of Sheet1. It
  ' finishes when it finds an empty column in row 1.
  Do While Wsht1.Cells(1, ColSht1Crnt).Value <> ""

    SearchValue = Wsht1.Cells(1, ColSht1Crnt).Value

    With Wsht2

      ' The value for After means the first cell examined is A2. The values for
      ' SearchOrder and SearchDirection means the search down the sheet from left
      ' to right.
      ' V1 Search for SearchValue.  V2 Search for anything starting with SearchValue
      Set RngFirst = .Cells.Find(What:=SearchValue & "*", After:=.Cells(1, Columns.Count), _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext)

      If RngFirst Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Print "There are no occurrences of [" & SearchValue & "]" & " in Sheet2"
      Else
        ' There is at least one occurence of SearchValue

        ' V1 Delete any locations recorded for the last SearchValue
        ' V2 Delete any values recorded for the last SearchValue
        Do While Locations.Count > 0
          Locations.Remove (1)
        Loop

        Set RngCrnt = RngFirst

        ' V1 Each repeat of this loop records the location of an occurrence of SearchValue
        ' V2 Each repeat of this loop records a value found that starts with SearchValue
        Do While True

          ' V1 Record location of SearchValue
          'Locations.Add (Replace(RngCrnt.Address, "$", ""))
          ' V2 Record value of cell starting SearchValue
          Locations.Add (RngCrnt.Value)

          Set RngCrnt = .Cells.FindNext(After:=RngCrnt)

          If RngCrnt.Address = RngFirst.Address Then
            ' Search has looped and has found first occurrence again
            Exit Do
          End If

        Loop

        ' V1 Debug.Print "[" & SearchValue & "]" & " has been found in Sheet2 in the following cells:";
        ' V1 For InxL = 1 To Locations.Count
        ' V1 Debug.Print " " & Locations(InxL);
        ' V1 Next
        ' V1 Debug.Print
        ' V2 Store values found under heading
        RowSht1Crnt = 2
        With Wsht1
          For InxL = 1 To Locations.Count
            .Cells(RowSht1Crnt, ColSht1Crnt).Value = Locations(InxL)
            RowSht1Crnt = RowSht1Crnt + 1
          Next
        End With

      End If

    End With

    ColSht1Crnt = ColSht1Crnt + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tony,
Thanks for your time and the great job. But still I need a small change here. In the same excel spreadsheet, please enter values like below in sheet2

Comment: In Sheet2, please type, i

Range ("a3") = 101abc
Range ("b2") = 101bca
Range ("c4") = 101abc
Range ("c4") = 101abc

Comment: After running the code,

In Sheet1 value should be like below based on the it's header i.e, range ("a1")

Range ("a2") = 101bca
Range ("a3") = 101abc
Range ("a4") = 101abc
Range ("a5") = Blank
Range ("a6") = 101abc

Likewise, I need to capture all the headers in sheet1. I mean the value can be available in anywhere in the row, we need to fetch under the header in Sheet1 on respective row. Hope this understands in better way! Thanks Tony!

Comment: In your examples, the values in Sheet2 are all of the form: 101xxx.  Are values of the form xxxx101 or xx101xx possible?

Comment: Hi Tony,

Only 101xxx should be considered here.